# Can I read a .xls Excel file's title using the xlrd python module?

Tags: python, xlrd, import-from-excel

I am trying to write a python script that will read an Excel file's title (not the filename, the actual title given to the file).  I've scoured the docs and stack overflow but I don't see a way to do it with xlrd. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I might do it?

Comment: what do you mean by the file's title?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the excel sheet name, you can use "sheet.name"
For example:

```
        import xlrd
        file = xlrd.openworkbook("C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/abc.xlsx")
        sheet = file.sheet_by_index(0)
        print(sheet.name)
```

This will print out the first sheet name.